# GLSL Motion Blur Jittering

Tags: glsl, motion-blur

I tried to implement a motion-blur post processing effect as described in GPU Gems 3 Chapter 27, but I am encountering issues because the blur jitters when i move the camera and does not work as expected.
This is my fragment shader:

```
varying vec3 pos;
varying vec3 normal;
varying vec2 tex;
varying vec3 tangent;
uniform mat4 matrix;
uniform mat4 VPmatrix;
uniform mat4 matrixPrev;
uniform mat4 VPmatrixPrev;
uniform sampler2D diffuseTexture;
uniform sampler2D zTexture;
void main() {
    vec2 texCoord = tex;
    float zOverW = texture2D(zTexture, texCoord).r;
    vec4 H = vec4(texCoord.x * 2.0 - 1.0, (1 - texCoord.y) * 2.0 - 1.0, zOverW, 1.0);
    mat4 inv1 = inverse(matrix);
    mat4 inv2 = inverse(VPmatrix);
    vec4 D = H*(inv2*inv1);
    vec4 worldPos = D/D.w;
    mat4 prev = matrixPrev*VPmatrixPrev;
    vec4 previousPos = worldPos*prev;
    previousPos /= previousPos.w;
    vec2 velocity = vec2((H.x-previousPos.x)/2.0, (H.y-previousPos.y)/2.0);
    vec3 color = vec3(texture2D(diffuseTexture, texCoord));
    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        texCoord += velocity;
        vec3 color2 = vec3(texture2D(diffuseTexture, texCoord));
        color += color2;
    }
    color /= 16;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
```

The uniforms `matrix` and `VPmatrix` are the ModelView and Projection matrixes that were got as following:

```
float matrix[16];
float VPmatrix[16];
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, matrix);
glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, VPmatrix);
```

The uniforms `matrixPrev` and `VPmatrixPrev` are the previous ModelView and Projection matrixes got as following after rendering: (in the code below `matrixPrev` and `VPmatrixPrev` are global variables)

```
for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    matrixPrev[i] = matrix[i];
    VPmatrixPrev[i] = VPmatrix[i];
}
```

All four matrixes are passed to the shader as following:

```
glUniformMatrix4fvARB(glGetUniformLocationARB(postShader, "matrix"), 16, GL_FALSE, matrix);
glUniformMatrix4fvARB(glGetUniformLocationARB(postShader, "VPmatrix"), 16, GL_FALSE, VPmatrix);
glUniformMatrix4fvARB(glGetUniformLocationARB(postShader, "matrixPrev"), 16, GL_FALSE, matrixPrev);
glUniformMatrix4fvARB(glGetUniformLocationARB(postShader, "VPmatrixPrev"), 16, GL_FALSE, VPmatrixPrev);
```

In the shader, the uniform zTexture is a texture containing the depth values of the frame buffer. (Not sure if they are divided by W)

I hoped the shader would work but what I get instead is that when i rotate the camera around the blur jitters really fast with subtle rotations. I tried rendering the zTexture and the result I get is a grayscale image so It seems alright. I also tried setting the fragment color to `H.xyz` and `previousPos.xyz` and while rendering `H.xyz` produces a colored screen, `previousPos.xyz` produces the same colored screen, except that when the camera rotates the colors seem to invert, so I suspect there is something wrong with extracting the world position from depth.

Am I missing something here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your code, you do the blur sampling 16 times. Notice that this means you need to sample 16x per pixel. That's a lot. Did you try reducing this to e.g. 4 times? Is the effect OK? Do you still see the jitter? It's hard to say anything based on the code alone, maybe some experiments will show what can be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

forget my previous answer, is a matrix  error:

matrix multiplications are in the wrong order or otherwise you must send transpose matrix (explaining why only the rotation was taken in acount, translation/scale components where messed up):

```
glUniformMatrix4fvARB(glGetUniformLocationARB(postShader, "matrix"), 16, GL_FALSE, matrix);
```

becomes

```
glUniformMatrix4fvARB(glGetUniformLocationARB(postShader, "matrix"), 1, GL_TRUE, matrix);
```

(note 16 was not the matrix size but the matrix count, so it should be only only one here)

Another note: you should compute inverse matrix and project*view result matrix in your main application, not the pixel shader: it's done once per pixels but should be done only once per frame!)

Past post note: Google "*RuinIsland_GLSL_Demo.zip*": it contains many good glsl sample, helped me solve this issue

Comment: you should edit your previous answer rather than posting another like this

Comment: I eventually gave up on that project, but while coding another one, i managed to implement motion blur successfully. One thing i noticed while implementing custom matrix stack on this new project was that i was supposed to pass 1 as an argument instead of 16, otherwise it would send a matrix full of zeroes. I assume this was the only error on my old project so i'm accepting this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I don't have an answer but just a clue:
I have EXACTLY the same problem as yours.
I guess I used the same material pointed by google and, like you, the blurring exists only when the camera rotates.

However I have a clue (the same as yours in fact): I think it is because the glsl shader around the net assume our depth texture contains z/w but, like me, you used a genuine depth texture filled using fixed pipeline.
So you only have z and you are missing w in the very first step.
Since "texture2D(zTexture, texCoord).r" does contain only z : we miss the computation to get zOverW.
In the end we are stuck halfway from window spce to to clip space.

I found this: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Compute_eye_space_from_window_space#From_NDC_to_clip
but my perspective projection matrix does not meet the requierements, perhaps it will help you.